# Validate whether a character is a specific letter or not?

Tags: java, validation, char, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to write a test program to test whether or not a sequence of numbers is a magic square. However, I'm trying to figure out how to correctly validate the user input. In short, I want to prompt users for an integer and continue doing so until they enter the letter 'x'. If they accidentally enter a letter instead of x before they are done, I want the program to give them a brief error before allowing the continuation of their input until x is entered.

Here's what I have right now:

```
public class TestSquare
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      Square numbers = new Square();

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter an integer(x to exit): ");
      int i = in.nextInt();
      char c = (char)(i + '0');

      while(Character.isDigit(c))
      {
         numbers.add(i);
         System.out.println("Enter an integer(x to exit): ");
         i = in.nextInt();
         c = (char)(i + '0');
      }
      if( c == 'x')
      {
         numbers.isSquare();
         numbers.isUnique();
         numbers.isMagic();
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("***Invalid Data Entry. Please Try Again or enter x to exit.***");
         i = in.nextInt();
         c = (char)(i + '0');
      }
   }
}
```

This lets me input integers just fine continuously, but the moment I input a letter (including x) the program runs into an error and stops.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            numbers.add(i);
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter an integer(x to exit): ");
                i = in.nextInt();
                c = (char) (i + '0');
            } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
              if (c == 'x') {
                numbers.isSquare();
                numbers.isUnique();
                numbers.isMagic();
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                System.out.println("***Invalid Data Entry. Please Try Again or enter x to exit.***");
                in = new Scanner(System.in);
                continue;
            }
            }
        }
```

I have added a try and catch block in the while loop. So if a user enters a character the program will not crash. Instead control will go to the catch block. Here you can check with the input which was not an integer if it is the char x. If yes, you can stop the execution using `System.exit(0);` if not you can continue with the process..

Comment: I tried your method and this time it allowed me to input the letter and print out the error message, but after that the program crashes again without giving me the chance to enter another input.

Comment: remove the System.exit(0). and add the following code

Comment: in = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: if (c == 'x') {
                    // your code here
                    in = new Scanner(System.in);
                    continue;
                } else {
                    in = new Scanner(System.in);
                    continue;
                }

Comment: It still doesn't work. Now it's just a continuous loop where it allows me to enter whatever I want without stopping the program at the appropriate places :/ .

Comment: I didnt get your objective. Do you need to stop the program if the user enters x?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to use those three methods if the user enters "x" and then end the program. I'd like the user to be able to enter Integers for as long as they want until they enter x. If the user enters a letter other than x, i'd like the small error message to display before they can continue entering integers. Sorry I didn't make that very clear.

Answer (score 0):

There is not way to check if `c == 'x'` since you are expecting an int from the user and if the user enter anything other than int an exception will be thrown. But there is no way to find out what that input was from the user. To avoid this problem you can have the user to enter some other integer to exit. Maybe -1.

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

**Only use `Scanner.nextInt()` when you're sure the input will work as an `int`. Use `Scanner.next()` for the plain `String` value.**

---

The key to answering this question is understanding where the code is converting between types: `String`, `int` and `char`. (Keeping really clear on this stuff takes practice, but it's worth it: it's so much easier to spot problems when you have a good sense for types!)

### The types

The `int` type is a kind of integer that can hold values as low as -2,000,000,000 and as high as 2,000,000,000.

The `char` type is a different kind of integer that can hold values from 0 to about 65,000, but the values are usually used to encode text characters: `'A'` is 65, `'B'` is 66, `'X'` is 88 and `'x'` is 120.

The `String` type is an object that holds a sequence of text characters in a row. It's useful for things like `"Hello"`, but a `String` is a `String` even if the characters look numeric: `"100"` is a `String` with three characters.

- `4` is an `int` with the value 4.
- `'4'` is a `char` with the value 52.
- `"4"` is a `String` of length 1. The first character in `"4"` is `'4'`.

### A positive, single-digit number

```
Enter an integer(x to exit):
4
```

When you type the number <kbd>4</kbd> on your keyboard and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, that is not actually an `int` yet. `java.util.Scanner` will see it as a String token. (To keep matters simple, I won't talk about `System.input` sees it or how `Scanner` finds a token.)

```java
int i = in.nextInt();
```

The java.util.Scanner `nextInt()` method parses that `String` token ("4") into an `int` (4).

Then, the posted code takes that `int` (4) and converts it to a `char` ('4'):

```
char c = (char) (i + '0');
```

This adds an `int` kind of integer to a `char` kind of integer. In our case, since `i` is 4 and `'0'` is 48, the program calculates `4 + 48 = 52` and stores that number 52 in the `char` slot called `c`. (Luckily, the numbers are small enough that they fit.)

So when the next `String` token from the input stream is `"4"`, the code runs both lines:

```
int i = in.nextInt(); // "4" converted to 4
char c = (char) (i + '0'); // 4 converted to '4'
```

So far so good.

### A single letter

```
Enter an integer(x to exit):
x
```

When you type the letter <kbd>x</kbd> on your keyboard and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the story is much shorter.

The next token is the `String` `"x"`. The `Scanner` method `nextInt()` reads the token and attempts to parse it into an `int`, but `"x"` doesn't fit the format so `nextInt()` throws an `InputMismatchException` exception.

The exception means that the program interrupts the normal flow of running, leaves all the variables where they were, and jumps straight to the closest matching `catch` block. When there's no matching `catch` block to jump to, Java's default one will kick in: print the exception, abort the program.

So when the next `String` token from the input stream is `"x"`, the code runs one line and jumps away before any variables change:

```
i = in.nextInt(); // throws exception, so i does not change
c = (char) (i + '0'); // never executed, so c does not change
```

The key takeaway is that `Scanner.nextInt()` only helps you process text like `"400"` and won't help you process text like `"x"`.

### What else is there?

The `Scanner` class has many more methods than `nextInt()`. There are two other methods that are particularly relevant to this case:

- `hasNextInt()` (`true` when the next token is "400", `false` when the next token is "hello")
- `next()` (gives you the next token)

The plain one, `next()`, is the most important - it returns the next `String` token on its own. No extra conversion. So if the next token is `"4"`, `next()` will return `"4"`. If the next token is `"x"`, `next()` will return `"x"`.

If you want to process the input as text -- that is, if you want to treat "x" differently from "a" or "hello", that's the one to use:

```
String token = in.next();
if (token.equals("x")) {
  System.out.println("Goodbye");
}
```

In fact, `nextInt()` is essentially a shortcut for `next()` followed by `Integer.parseInt()`.

### You have the power

Armed with your new, clearer, understanding of types and conversions, you probably have a few ideas on how to tackle input in various formats.

Perhaps your new structure might look something like this pseudo-code:

```
while there are more tokens available {
    is the next token suitable for integer parsing? {
        parse the next token as an integer
    } else {
        deal with the token in its plain string form
    }
}
```

Or maybe you'll decide that you don't actually need to use `int`s at all, and the string "4" is good enough for your purposes. Or maybe you can convert straight from "4" to '4'.

The world is your oyster!

---

### Bonus round

You might find some of the following tips helpful as you work on your new code:

- `"hello".charAt(0) == 'h'`
- `"400".charAt(0) == '4'`
- `Integer.parseInt("400", 10) == 400`

And if you really want to make sure you've got your types in the right place, consider the following cases:

- "400" (multi-digit number)
- "-400" (negative number)
- "400000" (fits in an `int` integer, doesn't fit in a `char` integer)
- "4x" (digit and non-digit together)
- "4 0 0" (separate tokens entered all together)

Good luck!

Comment: This is great and all, but you probably should put a tl;dr section.

Comment: @cricket_007 Fair point. I've added a summary at the top. It kind of spoils the pedagogic flow, but it's a closer fit to the Stack Overflow style.